# Error with User Validation in nextAuth and Next.js | MongoDB, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm new to learning and practicing nextAuth in Next.js 13.4 with MongoDB and Mongoose. I'm facing an issue that appears in the console:

**Error checking if user exists:  User validation failed: username: Username invalid, it should contain 8-20 alphanumeric letters and be unique!**.

With this error, I am unable to log in via Google to my site on localhost:3000. I understand that there may be a simple solution, but it's only my first day of studying.

I have a file called route.js located in the app -> api -> auth -> [...nextauth] directory.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

import User from '@models/user';
import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session }) {
            // store the user id from MongoDB to session
            const sessionUser = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
            session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();

            return session;
        },
        async signIn({ account, profile, user, credentials }) {
            try {
                await connectToDB();

                // check if user already exists
                const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email });

                // if not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
                if (!userExists) {
                    await User.create({
                        email: profile.email,
                        username: profile.name.replaceAll(' ', '').toLowerCase(),
                        image: profile.picture,
                        
                    });
                console.log(User);
                }


                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error checking if user exists: ', error.message);
                return false;
            }
        },
    },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

My database.js which contains 'connectToDB' function.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let isConnected = false; // track the connection

export const connectToDB = async () => {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

    if (isConnected) {
        console.log('MongoDB is already connected');
        return;
    }

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
            dbName: 'share_prompt',
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });

        isConnected = true;

        console.log('MongoDB connected');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

My model of user is next

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: [true, 'This Email already exist!'],
        required: [true, 'Email is required!'],
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Username is required!'],
        match: [
            /^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/,
            'Username invalid, it should contain 8-20 alphanumeric letters and be unique!',
        ],
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
    },
});

const User = models.User || model("User", UserSchema);
export default User
```

I understand that problem is somewhere here, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Your `await User.create({...})` method is passing the `username` property which is failing your `UserSchema` validation defined by the `match` condition regex. Try `console.log(profile.name.replaceAll(' ', '').toLowerCase())` directly after the `if (!userExists) {` statement to see what is actually being passed. If it looks good then there could be an issue with your regex.

Comment: You were right! The problem was in my regex, 'cause of my username was in Cyrillic symbols, and regex don't accept that!

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you solved it.